# Removing email from woocommerce edit account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove email field from woocommerce edit account page to prevent user from changing his email address.

it is so easy to remove the front-end part by editing myaccount/form-edit-account.php template. But it's just from the form.

I want to remove if from backend too, so no one can put text box with email name to the form and change the email.

the backend function which does the edit process is here

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-form-handler.php#L141

as you can see, there is no filter or action to exclude email from processing.

any help would be appreciated.

**Solution (thanks to @Reigel)**

As I said, I had removed the email field from the template file but a malicious user could inject an input field with account_email and change the email. What I wanted was to ignore the POSTED email, if there was any.

so using `woocommerce_save_account_details_errors` action, it's possible to do it

class example

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', array( $this, 'remove_email_from_edit_account_process' ), 10,
            2 );


    public function remove_email_from_edit_account_process( $errors, $user ) {
        if ( ! empty( $user->user_email ) ) {
            unset($user->user_email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: your link isn't related to my question. It's about billing fields but mine is about removing account_email from the backend process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `woocommerce_save_account_details_errors` action to give error message that the email field can't be change...

Comment: Thanks mate! I used that action to unset the email from the stdClass instance of user. so when someone tries to inject an html field for account_email to edit the email, it will be unset from the user instance and ignored. I will put the solution in the main question description.